# Star-Board discord.py issues

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using a json file in order to store the star-board channels for the guilds. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    star = await get_star_channels()

    if str(payload.message.guild.id) not in star:
        return

    starchannel = client.get_channel(star[str(payload.message.guild.id)])
    
    

    if payload.emoji == '⭐':
        if str(payload.message.guild.id) not in star:
            return

        if not payload.member.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
            await payload.message.channel.send("You don't have the permissions to star a message")
            return

        if len(payload.message.attachments) > 0:
            embed.set_image(url = payload.message.attachments[0].url)

        embed = discord.Embed(description = f"{payload.message.author}:\n\n{payload.message.content}\n\n**[Jump to message]({payload.message.jump_url})**", color = random.choice(colors_for_embeds1), timestamp = datetime.now())
        embed.set_author(name = f"{payload.member.name} starred a message", icon_url = payload.member.avatar_url)
        
        
        embed.set_footer(text = f"<#{payload.channel.id}>")

        
        await starchannel.send(embed = embed)
```

The problem I'm facing is that `'RawReactionActionEvent'` object has no attribute `'message'` or `'guild'` so there's no way I can get the `guild ID where the reaction was added` (It seems that way). Without accessing the guild ID, I cannot get the `star channel ID stored in the JSON file` because the `key of all the star-channel IDs is the guild ID`.

Comment: its guild_id and message_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `guild_id` and `message_id`

Below are all attributes of RawReactionActionEvent:

`message_id`

`user_id`

`channel_id`

`guild_id`

`emoji`

`member` Only for `on_raw_reaction_add`

`event_type`